# How can I get XWin to start as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, cygwin, x-windows

I'm running Cygwin on Windows XP. I want XWin to start as a Windows service. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't. Services are not supposed to have access to the<sup>1</sup> user's desktop** – this was actually [removed in Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx) – and without it, XWin is sort of useless.

**Just put XWin in your ["Startup" folder.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Run-a-program-automatically-when-Windows-starts)**

(<sup>1</sup> I said "the", but Windows XP has "Fast User Switching" on by default. There may be [multiple users logged in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676070) at the same time. Which session would XWin run on?)

---

*[Now, I'm going to hate myself for this, but]* you can run arbitrary programs as Windows services by using a Microsoft tool `srvany`, as described in Microsoft's KB article ["How To Create a User-Defined Service"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890). Along with it comes `instsrv` for easy installation. **Do not forget to change the account your service runs on.** Later, mark the service as "interactive" via `sc config svcname type= interact`, or via the Services manager (`services.msc`).

Comment: Great idea with the "Startup" folder; something so obvious, but I never thought about it.